# Django TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django

I deployed my website on the server  Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64

I don't know the main template list.html it doesn't work other templates are working normally.

[templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlHNO.jpg)

I checked the  access permissions files They are the same

[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xXyv.jpg)

Settings looks like this

```
"""
Django settings for INZ project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#wx61%!ioz(yba#e=t7jh-*&(!l#kri=^y%ik(x4m3j8oix+hq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['46.101.116.26']
EMAIL_HOST ='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER ='luke.rudzinski@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '#####'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'games'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'INZ.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'INZ.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases
```

On localhost everythings is fine . I have Windows 8.1 maybe it the reason of my issue , because on win there is different file structure

Comment: Note it's not a good idea to include your `SECRET_KEY` on Stack Overflow. You should change it.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows, your file system on Linux is case sensitive. Rename your file from `List.html` to `list.html` to match your code.

Comment: Thank you for quick help